How to setup Candy Machine that allows multiple users to mint NFTs from a collection?
I created a Metaplex Candy Machine NFT collection following this tutorial, but only the wallet that I used to create the program can mint the NFTs from this Candy Machine.
How can I set it up to allow multiple users to mint NFTs from my Candy Machine, including interaction from my program to the Candy Machine?

First of all this quicknode SDK is slightly outdated and using a deprecated SDK. It does not allow you to create the latest Version of Candy Machine V3 (which is Account Version 2) and will therefore not allow you to do stuff like royalty enforcement. You might want to use the umi based JS SDK instead.
You can find docs for it in the Metaplex Developer Hub
To answer your question directly though:
You need to add Candy Guards.  Until this is done only the Candy Machine Mint Authority (which by default is the creators wallet) can mint. When you add candy guards that authority changes.

I created a Candy Machine using the provided documentation.
Is it safe for my Dapp if I place this line of code on the front-end?
When minting an NFT, I found that I need to pass a new address for the NFT.
const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);

Yes. This singlet is only used once to create the nft and can not be used for anything after minting

So, are there any solutions to get the number of minted NFTs from the Candy Machine, please?

Yes. Use fetchCandyMachine(). It returns itemsAvailable (the whole amount you added to the CM and itemsRedeemed (the number of already minted NFTs)
https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/manage
